# Magento2 Checkout validation scrolls

Tags: magento2, checkout

In **Magento2**, Default checkout validation scrolls to the top after alter message shown by custom function.

How to stop the default scrolling function & to focus on the error field in the form?

The error field inconsistently showing in checkout page.

Comment: please check if this answer can help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/272369/how-to-stop-scrolling-to-first-validation-error-message-on-magento2-on-add-to-ca

Comment: Given answer in above link isn't working for me, Can you share your solution.