# How to stop scrolling to first validation error message on magento2 on add to cart?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.1

How to stop scrolling to top or first validation failure message

[image]

Comment: Did u find an answer? I am looking for the same.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Copy**

> MAGENTO_ROOT/**vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/validation.js**
>
> into **app/design/frontend/THEME_ROOT/web/mage/**

then delete (start in line 1956)

```
if (firstActive.length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: firstActive.offset().top
    });
    firstActive.focus();
}
```

become

```
if (firstActive.length) {                   
   firstActive.focus();
}
```

Comment: Overwriting the whole file just to remove 3 lines is not a good idea. See my answer for a solution with a JS mixin.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a solution with a mixin to avoid overwriting the whole file:

1) app/design/frontend/[THEME_VENDOR]/[THEME_NAME]/Magento_Theme/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'mage/validation': {
                'Magento_Theme/js/lib/mage/validation-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

2) app/design/frontend/[THEME_VENDOR]/[THEME_NAME]/Magento_Theme/web/js/lib/mage/validation-mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (widget) {

        $.widget('mage.validation', widget, {
            /**
             * Handle form validation. Focus on first invalid form field.
             *
             * @param {jQuery.Event} event
             * @param {Object} validation
             */
            listenFormValidateHandler: function (event, validation) {
                let firstActive = $(validation.errorList[0].element || []),
                    lastActive = $(validation.findLastActive() ||
                        validation.errorList.length && validation.errorList[0].element || []),
                    parent, windowHeight, successList;

                if (lastActive.is(':hidden')) {
                    parent = lastActive.parent();
                    windowHeight = $(window).height();
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: parent.offset().top - windowHeight / 2
                    });
                }

                // ARIA (removing aria attributes if success)
                successList = validation.successList;

                if (successList.length) {
                    $.each(successList, function () {
                        $(this)
                            .removeAttr('aria-describedby')
                            .removeAttr('aria-invalid');
                    });
                }

                if (firstActive.length) {
                    /* vertically center the first field on the screen. This is best for UX but if you prefer to avoid the scrolling completelly, just remove the next line and the function "scrollToCenterFormFieldOnError" below. */
                    scrollToCenterFormFieldOnError(firstActive);
                    firstActive.focus();
                }
            }
        });

        function scrollToCenterFormFieldOnError(firstActive) {
            let fieldTop = firstActive.offset().top,
                fieldHeight = firstActive.height(),
                windowHeight = $(window).height(),
                offset;

            offset = fieldTop - ((windowHeight / 2) - (fieldHeight / 2));

            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: offset
            });
        }

        return $.mage.validation;
    }
});
```

Comment: Works well... :D

Comment: Yes yes yes, proper answer!