# Magento 2 - Do not scroll to invalid field on form validation

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, jquery, validation, form-validation

On the log in page, when I don't input input in fields, the error message displays focusing on the invalid input. The window scrolls upto the invalid field at the same time.

I do not want the window to scroll.
Where can I find the code for scrolling?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop scrolling to first validation error message on magento2 on add to cart?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/272369/how-to-stop-scrolling-to-first-validation-error-message-on-magento2-on-add-to-ca)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

copy MAGENTO_ROOT/vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/validation.js
into app/design/frontend/THEME_ROOT/web/mage/

then comment (start in line 1956)

```
if (firstActive.length) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: firstActive.offset().top
                });
                firstActive.focus();
            }
```

become

```
if (firstActive.length) {
                /*$('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: firstActive.offset().top
                });*/
                firstActive.focus();
            }
```

or just delete

```
if (firstActive.length) {

                    firstActive.focus();
                }
```